# How to use a tensor to initialize a variable in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` and I get the following warning:

```
UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
```

I read in this [link](http://www.iterate.site/post/01-%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E7%9A%84%E5%BC%A0%E5%8A%9B/02-%E6%9C%BA%E5%99%A8%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0/02-%E6%9C%BA%E5%99%A8%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8/10-%E6%B7%B1%E5%BA%A6%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%E6%A1%86%E6%9E%B6/02-tensorflow/warning-converting-sparse-indexedslices-to-a-dense-tensor-of-unknown-shape/) that to avoid this issue we should ensure that the params input to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` is a `tf.Variable`

But what I pass to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` is already a tensor that is the output of another operation, and I imagine I cannot use it to initialize the `tf.Variable`.

Is there a way to convert a tensor to tf.Variable or initialize one with another tensor?

Comment: Hi, does my answer solve your doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A `tf.Variable` represents a **tensor** whose value can be changed by
>   running ops on it.
>
> Internally, a `tf.Variable` stores a **persistent tensor**.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables

You can initialize a tf.Variable with a **Tensor** object: `tf.Tensor`

```
# Create a variable.
w = tf.Variable(<initial-value>, name=<optional-name>)
```

**`initial_value`**: A Tensor, or Python object convertible to a Tensor, which is the initial value for the Variable.

The initial value must have a shape specified unless validate_shape is set to False. Can also be a callable with no argument that returns the initial value when called. In that case, dtype must be specified.

(Note that initializer functions from init_ops.py must first be bound to a shape before being used here.)

In summary, you can initialize a `tf.Variable` with another **Tensor** object.